# Passing variables before controller URI segment in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, uri

I would like to pass some site-wide validated variables before controller segment in URL.

Example:

Default URL would be:

```
www.mysite.com/controller/method/variable/
```

Sometimes I'd like to have also URL like this to refer to user created sub-configuration of this site (theme, menus, ...), so user could share this site URL nicely and others would see the site though his custom configurations.

```
www.mysite.com/username/controller/method/variable
```

Here **username** is custom part of **base_url**. It should be validated against database and set as session variable to use it later in my controllers and change theme for example. Also all the links on the site would start to use `www.mysite.com/username` as **base_url** after website is entered with this **username** in the URL.

One way to solve this would be routing it like this:

```
controller/method/variable_name1/variable_value1/user_conf/username
```

...and the add the implementation to every single controller in my project. But this is not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with this problem for a day I ended up with adding custom router class to my project. I'm working in CodeIgniter 2.0, so the location of this file should be `application/core/MY_Router.php`

My code is following:

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * OVERRIDE
 *
 * Validates the supplied segments.  Attempts to determine the path to
 * the controller.
 *
 * @access    private
 * @param    array
 * @return    array
 */
function _validate_request($segments)
{
    if (count($segments) == 0)
    {
        return $segments;
    }

    // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].EXT))
    {
        return $segments;
    }

    $users["username"] = 1;
    $users["minu_pood"] = 2;
    // $users[...] = ...;
    // ...
    // Basically here I load all the 
    // possbile username values from DB, memcache, filesystem, ...
    if (isset($users[$segments[0]])) { 
        // If my segments[0] is in this set
        // then do the session actions or add cookie in my cast.
        setcookie('username_is', $segments[0], time() + (86400 * 7));
        // After that remove this segment so 
        // rounter could search for controller!
        array_shift($segments); 
        return $segments;
    }

    // So segments[0] was not a controller and also not a username...
    // Nothing else to do at this point but show a 404
    show_404($segments[0]);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2/$1';
```

where all your function definitions have the username as the last parameter:

```
class Controller{function page(var1, var2, ..., varn, username){}}
```

Or, if you only want in on one specific page you could do something like this:

```
$route['(:any)/controller/page/(:any)'] = 'controller/page/$2/$1'; //This will work for the above class.
```

Or, if you want it for a number of functions in a controller you could do this:

```
$route['(:any)/controller/([func1|func2|funcn]+)/(:any)'] = 'controller/$2/$3/$1';
```

Comment: That's a good explanation about using router class, but it's not exactly what I was looking for, because adding additional input parameter for all the methods in all the controllers would be trouble.