# Additional URI segment before Codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, uri, codeigniter-url

I'm making this little project in Codeigniter and I need to have one additional segment before controller.
The default Codeigniter URL is:

```
base_url/controller/function/parameter1/../parametern
```

What I need is:

```
base_url/something/controller/function/parameter1/../parametern
```

Where "something" is a name that user creates so I cant create a subfolder in controllers folder as suggested in other topics because its dynamic and each user chooses what he likes.

Basically what I need is that it like ignores that segment (I would catch that segment in a hook, extend CI_controller or something like that and validate it), for example if I write **base_url/stackoverflow-rocks/home/function**, **base_url/asd-whatever/home/function** Codeigniter would look at it like **base_url/home/function**

I have also looked at [Passing variables before controller URI segment in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233833/passing-variables-before-controller-uri-segment-in-codeigniter) question, its almost the same as mine but the suggested answer didn't work.
I used `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2';` which works if the url is base_url/whatever/home, but if the url is base_url/whatever/home/function or base_url/whatever/home/function/param1/../paramn it doesn't, the workaround for this is to write:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2';  
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2/$3';  
...  
$route['(:any)/../(:any)'] = '$2/../$n'
```

which is easy, but seems a bit lame, and it will only work if I have from 2 to n segments in url. I also tried to mix it with regular expressions, like:

```
$route['(:any)/(.*)'] = '$2'
```

But it works just like the previous one, (.*) is just one segment but not the whole url... 
Is there some way to just write
`$route['(:any)/rest of the url'] = 'rest of the url';`?
I also tried using .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*) inedx.php?/$2
```

or

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?/$2
```

But it didn't work because $2 referenced to the first part, for example if I write:
base_url/one/two it rewrites it to base_url/index.php?/one. 
But if I use:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?/$1/test/$2
```

it references as it should, for example base_url/one/two => base_url/index.php?/one/test/two, so $1 = one and $2 = two, as it should be.

Quite a long question but I hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see if this works:

```
$route['base_url/controller/(:any)'] = 'base_url/$1'
```

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I need, it ignores "controller" or other name that is hard-coded. Maybe a better example: I have a blog system with controller post, function edit and parameter id. If users blog name is "whatever" to edit a post with id 123 the url would be: example.com/whatever/post/edit/123 It would execute post controllers edit method with id 123, other user has a blog "asd" to edit a post he goes example.com/asd/post/edit/456. I'd get the blog name(whatever/asd in a hook or something like that)and check if there is a blog with that name, but that's not important here.