# Passing variables before controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I want to pass some variables to my URL before controller name
let's suppose my  URL looks like `http://mysite/controller/function/etc/etc`
and I want to call it as `http://mysite/username/controller/......`
I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233833/passing-variables-before-controller-uri-segment-in-codeigniter) but it did not work for me.

my routes.php looks like

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['(:any)/index'] = "index/index/$1";
$route['(:any)/test'] = "test/page/$1";
```

this some how solves my problem but I have to pass the controller name for the default controller as well.
Is there any way to do like if I go to `http://mysite/username`, it should go to default controller???

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206065/how-to-organize-country-state-city-browsing-in-codeigniter/24206510#24206510

Comment: @Dan already looked into this, this working fine for `static` variables as said in the above question, my `username` is changed dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller = Index, Function = getUser

Change routes to

```
$route['(:any)/index'] = "index/getUser/$1"
```

And add to index controller

```
public function getUser($username) {
    //return user's page html
}
```

This assumes url style of

> http://www.example.com/username/index

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want `index` in my URL

Comment: This index was used as a controller name...feel free to change it to something different

Comment: What if i want to do like `mysite/username` should go to index controller?

Comment: I would create a user controller. 
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/$1"
With this, just add the function to call after 'user/' in the url
eg www.example.com/user/add would call 'user' controller and 'add' function